# Jquery to accept only first td as zero

Tags: jquery

I have grid where user can enter values. By default 5 rowsare shown..if user want more he can click on add a new row will get added. I want to put the validation if user enter zero in first column on click of add it should allow you to add new row instead of firing validation "Please fill all base incentive rows" attached image for reference.[image]

```
 var addBtnValidation = function () {
        $('#stepBaseIncentive').on('click', '.AddGlobalKicker', function () {
            var biTable = $(this).parent('div').find('.PCVPropDetail');
            var counter = 0;
            biTable.find("input[type=text]").each(function(i,e) {
                if (e.value == 0)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            })
            if (counter > 0) {
                window.alerts.showAlert({
                    message: "Please fill all base incentive rows",
                    alertClass: 'alert-danger'
                });
                return false;
            }
            else {

                var newrow = biTable.find('tr:last').clone();
                newrow.find("input[type=text]").each(function (i, e) {
                    var oldId = e.id;
                    var oldName = e.name;
                    var idCounter = e.id.split('BaseIncentiveItems_')[1].charAt(0);
                    var newIdCounter = parseInt(idCounter) + 1;
                    e.id = oldId.replace(idCounter, newIdCounter);
                    e.name = oldName.replace(idCounter, newIdCounter);
                    e.value = 0;
                })
                biTable.append(newrow);
                return true;
            }

        })
    }
```

I want this type of data and when user click on Add he should be able to add new row but my code does not allow to do so..focus on first row value is zero.Currently i am checking in the code if anywhere zero comes it should throw validation either it should not check for first row.
[image]

Comment: I am very confused by the question.

Comment: See updated image and comments

Comment: Can you create a fiddle  including the HTML code?

Comment: Have you checked if the click is actually working? Have you checked what values are you getting for `e.value` inside the loop? Is the `counter` actually increasing?

Comment: Everything in the code is working except it is firing validation message if first row is zero which i dont want...counter is also increasing

Comment: why not do your validation in real-time rather than on addition of a new row? where you hook into the 'change' of a value. That way, you only apply the validation to the cells you actually want to be checked (ie. All rows after the first)

Comment: you can give there `if (counter > 0 && first_val != 0)` where first_val will be the value of first td in first row (first-child selectors)